# a local variable `texture’ cannot be declared in this scope because it will give a different mean to texture

Tags: c#, unity3d

Eu sou novo no c# script em unity3d
Recebo um erro no `EditorFacebookMockDialog.cs`:

> a local variable `texture’ cannot be declared in this scope because it will give a different mean to texture
>   como posso resolver este erro?

O codigo

```
namespace Facebook.Unity.Editor
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    internal abstract class EditorFacebookMockDialog : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public delegate void OnComplete(string result);

        public OnComplete Callback { protected get; set; }

        public string CallbackID { protected get; set; }

        protected abstract string DialogTitle { get; }

        public void OnGUI()
        {
            if ( this.modalStyle == null )
            {
                this.modalRect = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, Screen.height - 20);
                this.modalStyle = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.window);
                Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
                texture.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f));
                texture.Apply();
                this.modalStyle.normal.background = texture;
            }

            var rect = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, Screen.height - 20);
            Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
            texture.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f));
            texture.Apply();
            var style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.window);
            style.normal.background = texture;


            GUI.ModalWindow(
                this.GetHashCode(),
                rect,
                this.OnGUIDialog,
                this.DialogTitle,
                style);
        }

        protected abstract void DoGui();

        protected abstract void SendSuccessResult();

        protected void SendCancelResult()
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dictionary[Constants.CancelledKey] = true;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CallbackID))
            {
                dictionary[Constants.CallbackIdKey] = this.CallbackID;
            }

            this.Callback(MiniJSON.Json.Serialize(dictionary));
        }

        protected void SendErrorResult(string errorMessage)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            dictionary[Constants.ErrorKey] = errorMessage;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CallbackID))
            {
                dictionary[Constants.CallbackIdKey] = this.CallbackID;
            }

            this.Callback(MiniJSON.Json.Serialize(dictionary));
        }

        private void OnGUIDialog(int windowId)
        {
            GUILayout.Space(10);
            GUILayout.BeginVertical();
            GUILayout.Label("Warning! Mock dialog responses will NOT match production dialogs");
            GUILayout.Label("Test your app on one of the supported platforms");
            this.DoGui();
            GUILayout.EndVertical();

            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
            var loginLabel = new GUIContent("Send Success");
            var buttonRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(loginLabel, GUI.skin.button);
            if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, loginLabel))
            {
                this.SendSuccessResult();
                MonoBehaviour.Destroy(this);
            }

            var cancelLabel = new GUIContent("Send Cancel");
            var cancelButtonRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(cancelLabel, GUI.skin.button);
            if (GUI.Button(cancelButtonRect, cancelLabel, GUI.skin.button))
            {
                this.SendCancelResult();
                MonoBehaviour.Destroy(this);
            }

            var errorLabel = new GUIContent("Send Error");
            var errorButtonRect = GUILayoutUtility.GetRect(cancelLabel, GUI.skin.button);
            if (GUI.Button(errorButtonRect, errorLabel, GUI.skin.button))
            {
                this.SendErrorResult("Error: Error button pressed");
                MonoBehaviour.Destroy(this);
            }

            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As perguntas aqui devem estar em português :) lembre de adicioanar a tag linguagem também.

Comment: Mesmo as mensagens de erro? Para quem tem dificuldade com inglês isso é um grande impeditivo.

Comment: @Cleiton Mas ele não estava falando das mensagens de erro...

Answer (score 2):

Você não pode declarar duas variáveis com o mesmo nome (`texture`), mesmo que uma delas esteja dentro do `if`.

Apenas mude o nome de uma das variáveis.

```
if (this.modalStyle == null)
{
    //...
}

var rect = new Rect(10, 10, Screen.width - 20, Screen.height - 20);
Texture2D texture2 = new Texture2D(1, 1);
texture2.SetPixel(0, 0, new Color(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f));
texture2.Apply();
var style = new GUIStyle(GUI.skin.window);
style.normal.background = texture2;
```

Comment: Ao invés de alterar o nome o melhor neste exemplo seria deslocar a primeira declaração para cima do if e remover a segunda.

Comment: Por que é melhor? Pare pra analisar o código com a sua dica. Se o resultado de `modalStyle` for `null` será criado um objeto do tipo `Texture2D`, haverão algumas modificações no objeto e depois `modalStyle.normal.background` receberá uma referência para este objeto. Logo depois, o objeto será **modificado novamente**, isto é, **`modalStyle.normal.background`** terá suas propriedades alteradas. Se for pra fazer isso, qual é o sentido de ter o bloco de código dentro do `if`?

Comment: Ficou faltando um `else` para dar sentido a este condicional. Note que a condição apenas trata um desvio de como essa instancia deveria ser configurada.

Comment: [...] Claro que falta um pouco de atenção do OP. deveria ter um `else` no código, ou então o segundo bloco de código deveria setar outra propriedade que não fosse `style.normal.background`, mas isso é outro problema.

Comment: Verdade, do jeito está dá margem para interpretações.

Comment: Sim, @Cleiton. Este é um grande mal de perguntas mal escritas. Sorte que, neste caso, não chega a afetar o "escopo principal" da pergunta que é o problema de ter duas variáveis com o mesmo nome. Apenas conseguimos ver (outras) falhas no código que não são a(s) apontada(s) na pergunta.